# Mixed content error for http express route

Tags: node.js, http, express, https, routes

I'm running a local node js server on my machine and I provide it with a `ngrok.io` domain.

If I run it local in the web browser with `localhost:3000` or with `http://1234.ngrok.io` everything is ok. If I call it with `httpS://1234.ngrok.io` I get the error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://1234.ngrok.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:3000/calculation'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

caused because the route is not http. How can I fix this?

This is the app.js on my node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../Client'));

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./https_certificate/client-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./https_certificate/client-cert.pem')
};

app.listen(server_connection.port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + server_connection.port);
    //do stuff
});

//load the index.html from the server
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../Client/index.html'));
});
```

This is the other file with the route who causes the error:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express();
router.post('/calculation', function(req, res) {
 //do stuff
}
```

I already tried to configure the server for https how you can see on the `options` object in the first file but this resolved in a 502 Bad Gateway.

I also would like to use just https. Is it possible to redirect to https if someone uses http?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are sending an ajax request using `http` to the server, make sure that all your ajax calls are over `https` to get ride from this error.